# phpstorm не видит атрибуты angularjs material

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm

phpstorm не видит атрибуты angularjs material. В проект добавил lib ангуляра. Плагин angularjs https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs последней версии не ставиться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за ответ.

Вообщем установлена версия 171.4694.2, а последняя версия 172.2273.2 я так понял она не совместима.
( ссылка на плагин https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вообщем стандартные некоторые атрибуты видны, а некоторые нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно поставить AngularJS плагин, совместимый с вашей версией PhpStorm. Для этого нужно снести несовместимый плагин и поставить новый, используя кнопку `Install JetBrains plugin...`. Кроме того, необходимо добавить отладочную версию `angular.js`  в проект - судя по скриншоту, у Вас есть только минифицированная (`angular.min.js`)

Comment: а как узнать какой плагин совместим, а какой нет?

Comment: `Install JetBrains plugin...` всегда предлагает последнюю совместимую версию. Конечно, бывают сбои из-за неправильно написанных дескрипторов и т.п., но они,как правило,быстро устраняются. Обращаю ваше внимание: не `Install from disk`, а `Install JetBrains plugin...`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ обновил вопрос. установлена версия 171.4694.2, а последняя версия 172.2273.2 я так понял она не совместима. Вообщем некоторые атрибуты видны, а некоторые нет.

Comment: значит, phpstorm по какой-то причине не нашел объявление соотв директивы. Понять, почему, можно только с проектом:(

Comment: А у вас phpStorm видит тег md-dialog-content и атрибуты md-button ? Это пустой проект созданный при помощи CLI.

Comment: эээ... Что-то я запуталась. Из всего, что Вы писали раньше, я сделала вывод, что Вы используете AngularJS. Но теперь вы пишете про cli (полагаю, angular-cli?). Зачем тогда были эти пляски с бубном вокруг angular.js, material.js и проч., которые Вы добавляли в библиотеки? Или я что-то упустила?